# How to change the color of marker-points dynamically based on y-position

Tags: javascript, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have below interactive plot using `highchart` `js` library in `R`

```
library(highcharter)
hchart(data.frame('Date' = seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() - 10, by = '-1 day'), 'Value' = sample(c(-1, 1), 11, replace = T), 'variable' = 'aa') %>% mutate(color = ifelse(Value < 0, "#41c83b", "#E0245E")), 
                            "line", 
                            zIndex = 1, opacity = 0.9,
                            hcaes(x = Date, y = Value, group = variable),
                            zones = list(list(value = 0, color = hex_to_rgba("#41c83b", 1)), list(color = hex_to_rgba("#E0245E", 1))),
                            marker = list(fillColor = "#fff", lineColor = '#000', radius = 5, lineWidth = 2))
```

I wanted to match the color of `markers` based on the line color which is dynamic based on the `y-value`. Currently color of all markers as set as `black` which I did not want.

Any pointer how to change the color dynamically will be highly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no such option in the API. You need to write some custom code.
The simplest way is to use chart.events.load event, loop through all points of your series, find the ones in the red or green zone and update their marker options separately.
To write a JavaScript code in R, you can use JS("") function.

Here is the whole sample code:

```
library(highcharter)
hchart(data.frame('Date' = seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() - 10, by = '-1 day'), 'Value' = sample(c(-1, 1), 11, replace = T), 'variable' = 'aa') %>%
         mutate(color = ifelse(Value < 0, "#41c83b", "#E0245E")), 
       "line", 
       zIndex = 1, opacity = 0.9,
       hcaes(x = Date, y = Value, group = variable),
       zones = list(list(value = 0, color = hex_to_rgba("#41c83b", 1)), list(color = hex_to_rgba("#E0245E", 1))),
       marker = list(fillColor = "#fff", radius = 5, lineWidth = 2)) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function () {
    this.series[0].points.forEach(function (point) {
      if (point.y > 0) {
        point.update({
          marker: {
            lineColor: 'red'
          }
        }, false);
      } else {
        point.update({
          marker: {
            lineColor: 'green'
          }
        }, false);
      }
    });
    this.redraw();
  }")))
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update