# Changing colors of chart elements in r-highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have line chart with 25 lines, but want to color only 3 of them and others make grey, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Highcharter's `hc_chart` function to include [chart.events.load](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) event in which you can fire custom JavaScript code. Use `JS("")` function to inject JavaScript code into R.
In that JavaScript code, you can loop through all series and update their colors using `series.update()` method.

**I did exactly the same today here:** [How to change the color of marker-points dynamically based on y-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091113/how-to-change-the-color-of-marker-points-dynamically-based-on-y-position/62133285#62133285)
but instead of series, I changed the markers' color.

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Here is a JavaScript demo showing it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cyhd5Ln2/

```
var series = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    series.push({
        data: [5 + i, 6 + i, 3 + i, 4 + i]
    });
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                this.series.forEach(function (series, i) {
                    if (i < 3) {
                        series.update({
                            color: 'red'
                        }, false);
                    } else {
                        series.update({
                            color: 'grey'
                        }, false);
                    }
                });
                this.redraw();
            }
        }
    },

  series: series

});
```

Instead of updating the chart 15 times (which is a performance killing when you have more series), I updated with `redraw flag: false` and after the `for loop` I did `chart.redraw()` just once.