# HighCharts: Want to use different Data source during hc_tooltup building than data source used in X and Y axis in my R Shiny App

Tags: r, highcharts, shinyapps

I want to use different data source while building hc_tooltip in my Line type Highchart. Its a custom tool tip. So just to summarize in case I am using `dataSource1` in my `hc_add_series` like this:

```
highchart() %>% hc_add_series(**dataSource1** )
```

I would like to bring data from `dataSource2` during `hc_tooltip`. Is it possible even? Will really appreciate a response.

Comment: Have you tried it? A small reprex will enable others to help you.

Comment: I would like to make sure that I understand the question correctly, it means that for one series with a specific date (for each point) you would like to display this data in a different way in the tooltip (different data set)? If not, could you please explain in more detail how it should work. It will probably also be helpful if you send us your code so that we can better see what you mean.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. I was able to figure this out. It was actually pretty simple. I was just not using right approach. Stuck on next issue in HighChart.  What I want is build dynamic Tool Tip. Example in below line of code can I call a function which will fetch some rows to build my ToolTip. For Example when I hover mouse on scatter point right now in below code its picking from columns as in supplied data frame. What I want is go to some other data frame and pick records from there for my tool tip. BTW I am using Shiny R. Will really appreciate help

Comment: Forgot to add TOOL TIP code I am currently using which I want to enhance: hc <- hc %>% hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, backgroundColor = "#FCFFC5",shared=FALSE,useHTML=TRUE,footerFormat = '</table>',headerFormat= '<span style="font-size:10px"></span><table>',followPointer=TRUE, borderWidth = 2, pointFormat= paste0('<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.PfId}-{series.name}</h3></th>','<tr><th>Risk:</th><td>{point.x}</td></tr>','<tr><th>Return:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>'))

Comment: So you just want to build a dynamic tooltip (dynamic I mean some function that builds a table and retrieves data from another place) - for this, you will need to use a formatter because it runs the function as a callback:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

To write JavaScript code in R, you can use the JS function (""). You can see a similar topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091113/how-to-change-the-color-of-marker-points-dynamically-based-on-y-position/62133285#62133285

Comment: Thanks. I am less technical in using Javascript so will have some struggle in writing. There is no other alternate way within R to achieve this goal?

Comment: There is no alternative in R because the formatter is in the core highcharts and it is called by formatter.apply (this, arguments) and that's JS:

library('highcharter')
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(5, 4, 3, 5)
  ) %>%
  hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function(){
    return ('y: ' + this.y)
  }"))

Comment: Here you can also find this simplified example with data.frame:
library('highcharter')
data <- data.frame(y = c(2,3,2, 5), aaa = c('first', 'test', 'something', 'fourth'))
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = data
  ) %>%
  hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function(){
    return ('y: ' + this.y + ' <br> Number of gears: ' + this.point.aaa)
  }"))

Comment: Thanks again for passing info. Let me explain with the data sets I have and what I am really looking for. My first Data set from which I prepare my highchart consists of 3 columns Pf, Return, Risk. Lets say it has 2 rows PF1, 2, 3. Second Row PF2, 3,4. Values from Risk are plotted at X and Return at Y Axis. Now I have another data set with columns as Pf, StockSymbol, Weights which is basically an expansion of Pf values from first dataset. It has rows as Pf1, MSFT, 2 and PF2, FB, 3. When I hover my mouse on scatter chart, PF1 from first data set should get values from second data set and so on

Comment: To do this in Javascript within Formatter function I guess I will have to run a loop by key value PF1 or PF2 from first data set and loop in second because second data set can contain multiple rows for PF1 or PF2. Thats challenge for me and not able to work my brain around. What I can't figure out that at Client side (within Browser) how my second data set will be accessed. What exactly I need to do in my Server side code of R to achieve this?

Comment: So, I think that a bit more advanced configuration comes into play here. Unfortunately, I don't know R well enough to be able to advise here.